# Selecting a specific libstdc++ version with clang

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, clang, libstdc++

I use `clang++` for compiling C++ code. I link against the `gcc` standard C++ library, `libstdc++`. However, I have several different installation of `libstdc++` on my Ubuntu machine. When I run `clang++`, it uses the 4.8 installation of `libstdc++`:

```
andy@andy:~$ clang++-3.5 -v
Ubuntu clang version 3.5.0-4ubuntu2~trusty2 (tags/RELEASE_350/final) (based on LLVM 3.5.0)
Target: i386-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.4
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8.4
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9.3
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.4
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8.4
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9.3
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8
Candidate multilib: .;@m32
Selected multilib: .;@m32
```

How can I tell `clang++` to use a different version of the `libstdc++` library and headers? specifically, I want to use the 4.6 version.

Comment: Have you tried to use an old version of `clang`?

Comment: @NarekAtayan In a similar system where `gcc` 4.8 is not installed, the same version of `clang` (specifically 3.4) uses `gcc` 4.6. So it is possible without using a different version of `clang`.

Comment: Hmm, could be [impossible](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2016-March/047856.html)

Comment: Have you tried using `--gcc-toolchain=/path/to/gcc/prefix` command line option? As mentioned [here](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html), it should make Clang use specific version of GCC toolchain, including the `libstdc++` along with `clang++`:

"Clang will look within its own prefix for libstdc++ and use it if found. You can also add an explicit prefix for Clang to look in for a GCC toolchain with the --gcc-toolchain=/opt/my/gcc/prefix flag, passing it to both compile and link commands".

Answer (score 11):

As you have seen from the output of `clang++ -v`, it will default to the latest installation of gcc it finds in a given "prefix" (i.e. installation directory).

The problem with the way multiple versions of gcc are installed e.g. on Ubuntu is that they all use the same prefix, `/usr`.

So, the workaround I am using is to create a bunch of fake installations, each under its own prefix: `/usr/local/gcc/5.5.0`, `/usr/local/gcc/6.4.0`, `/usr/local/gcc/7.3.0`, etc.:

```sh
VERSION=6.4.0
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/gcc/$VERSION/include/c++
sudo ln -s /usr/include/c++/$VERSION /usr/local/gcc/$VERSION/include/c++/$VERSION
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/gcc/$VERSION/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/$VERSION /usr/local/gcc/$VERSION/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/$VERSION
```

Now I can instruct `clang++` to use a specific version of gcc's libraries with the `--gcc-toolchain` option:

```
clang++ --gcc-toolchain=/usr/local/gcc/6.4.0 ...
```